# Set Flex Titlewindow background to transparent

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have a modal Flex dialog and want to make the background not of the window itself, but the semitransparent modal indicator transparent. (Yes I tried to convince the client they don't want to do this, but apparently they really want to do it). Is this even possible?

(prefer a solution using Flex 3's TitleWindow, but Spark/Flex 4 TitleWindow is acceptable)

Comment: "...but the semitransparent modal indicator..."  - Please clarify what you are referring to here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I think I phrased the question wrong, but this is the answer I was looking for:
http://www.learnosity.com/techblog/index.cfm/2007/4/25/Disable-the-blur-effect-in-Flex-PopupManager-modal-background

to paraphrase add:

```
global{
   modalTransparencyBlur: 0;
}
```

to the flex CSS and you're good; You can also make the modalTransparency 0 which will actually do what I said I wanted, but I think I'm going to try to convince my client that disabling the blur is all they needed (they want to be able to read the text under the popups)

(I wanted to disable the background of the PopUpManager not the TitleWindow)

Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not to have a definite answer, but have you tried setting the property

backgroundAlpha="0"

?

Comment: Technically backgroundAlpha is a style; not a property; although your syntax for setting it in MXML is correct.  The ActionScript approach is different for settings styles vs properties.

Answer (score 0):

For flex 3; have you tried specifying the alpha on the TitleWindow?  Based on a quick review of the code; it does not appear to pass the alpha down to the children (such as the close button, title bar, or title bar background.

Using the Spark Architecture; you should be able to do this easily with a custom skin.